# Error variables PHP en conexión con Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo este código

```
global $conexion;
global $fecha;
  $fecha=strftime( "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time() );

$conexion=null;
function conectar()
{global $conexion;
  $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "admin", "admin");
 mysqli_set_charset($conexion,'utf8');
}
function desconectar(){
  global $conexion;
  mysqli_close($conexion);
```

y me genera este error

```
 Severity: Warning --> mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
```

¿Que podría estar mal?

Comment: Tienes un lío con tus globales. El error ocurre porque intentas cerrar la conexión siendo esta nula. Recomendaría que no uses globales (usarlas se considera casi siempre una mala práctica y en tu caso lo es clarísimamente), ni siquiera necesitas un método `desconectar`, solamente cuando no necesitas conexión la cierras. No sé por qué quieres complicarte la vida con el código que muestras.

Answer (score 1):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Creo que intentar implementar el código que muestras es complicarse la vida por varios motivos:

1. En PHP las globales no funcionan como uno cree (no son globales) en el sentido propio de la palabra (demostración al final)
2. Aunque funcionasen como globales, para este caso y para casi todos los casos el uso de globales se considera una mala práctica. Imagina que en una parte cualquiera del código se cambia el estado de la variable global, se desconecta, se cambia la base de datos, etc. Imagina en una instrucción `INSERT` o `DELETE` que toma otro camino o cosas parecidas.
3. No tiene sentido tener un método `desconectar`, cuando `mysqli` dispone de su propio método de desconexión, o cuando puedes asignar `NULL` al objeto y con eso ya se desconectaría.

Puedes escribir tu código así:

> ```
> function conectar()
> {
>     mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "admin", "admin");
>     mysqli_set_charset($conexion,'utf8');
>     return $conexion;
> }
> ```

Ahora, dado que la función te retorna una conexión, puedes hacer esto cuando necesites la conexión:

```
$mysqli=conectar();
```

Luego, usas `$mysqli` y cuando no la necesites, la cierras con:

```
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

O si prefieres el estilo orientado a objetos:

```
$mysqli->close();
```

O, simplemente:

```
$mysqli=NULL;
```

Eso es todo, son sólo dos líneas de código.

Como comprenderás, querer cerrar la conexión mediante:

```
desconectar();
```

No es otra cosa que intentar reinventar la rueda. Aparte de que te obliga a declarar de nueeeevo dentro de la función una variable `global` según lo que PHP entiende por *global*.

---

#### Demostración de lo dicho en el punto 1

En PHP, las variables declaradas como `global` no funcionan como uno cree. Generalmente se entiende que una global tendría validez en todo el ámbito de un script o de un programa. En PHP no ocurre eso.

Veamos este ejemplo sencillo:

```
function conectar()
{
    $conexion = "conexion ok";
    return $conexion;

}

function desconectar(){
  //global $conexion;
  $conexion=null;
}

$conexion=conectar();
var_dump($conexion);
desconectar();
var_dump($conexion);
```

La salida por pantalla es:

```
string(11) "conexion ok"
string(11) "conexion ok"
```

¿Por qué al llamar `desconectar()`  la variable no se seteó a `NULL`? Porque no es una variable global realmente. Para que se setee a `NULL` hay que declararla de nueeeevo dentro de `desconectar()`:

```
function desconectar(){
  global $conexion;
  $conexion=null;
}
```

Ahora sí tendremos:

```
string(11) "conexion ok"
NULL
```

Realmente en PHP, las verdaderas variables globales se usan con `$GLOBALS`.

Veamos un ejemplo sólo a modo de prueba:

```
function conectar()
{
    $conexion = "conexion ok";
    return $conexion;
}

function desconectar(){
    $GLOBALS['trueGlobal']=null;
}

$trueGlobal= $GLOBALS['trueGlobal'] =conectar();
var_dump($trueGlobal);
desconectar();
var_dump($trueGlobal);
```

**Salida:**

```
string(11) "conexion ok"
NULL
```

Aquí sí `$trueGlobal` trabaja como una verdadera variable global. Es un tema que causa mucha confusión en PHP. En todo caso, desaconsejaría el uso de variables globales para esto.